# Manipulating SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, the structure of which I have simplified to the smaller table below.

I want to manipulate the dataset below into the following form:

The new dataset will contain a single record for each case of DC, with a yes/no flag indicating if the NatureOfTumour has changed from DC to IN, and the time taken to change from DC to IN if applicable.

The change from DC to IN will be considered only if location has remained the same i.e. only those records should be considered where NatureOfTumour has changed from DC to IN and the location remained the same. ItemNo is the unique ID.

On a community member's advice I have pasted the table in text below as well, cleaned up as best as I could. The last column "Gen" is empty. ItemNo is the unique ID. Copying the text below to excel and doing a text-to-columns (separated by spaces) should give you the original table in a readable format. Sorry cant think of a better way to paste the table here.

```
ItemNo   DateOfTest   NatureOfTumour     Location     Centre     Gen
2345     07/2006      DC                 P            S-224
2345     12/2006      IN                 P            S-224
2342     05/2004      DC                 Q            B-266
3878     06/2006      DC                 P            S-224
3878     05/2005      DC                 Q            S-224
5678     09/2000      IN                 P            S-224
5597     10/2001      DC                 P            B-266
5597     01/1999      IN                 Q            B-266
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Also, please don't post screenshots, provide information as text.

Comment: I did similar thing on MySQL. I added 2 tables. The first one is with the original data. The second is the same but with a date of edit. Where I can track any change on each unique ID and on whatever field I want with knowing the date. The relation is `1 to many`. I posted the question here on SO. Let me find it.

Comment: Sorry guys, still getting used to the best ways to post a question here. I have changed the image (table) to simple text now which should be easy to copy onto excel and do a text-to-columns onto

Comment: Your formatted text looks great now! Just like most people here want it.

Comment: Thanks jarlh & droidnation

Comment: When data of an ID is changed from DC to IN, Update your current table row, and in the new table add a new row with the same info but with a date. By that you will know when the changes occured.

Comment: Can you add the expected output based on that sample data? From your explanation I would think you only want one row for itemno=5597 in the output?

Comment: Hi Guys. Thanks for the replies, much appreciated. Unfortunately I would not be able to test the codes until I get back to work on Monday. a_horse_with_no_name the output would have only one row yes, but it would be for ItemNo=2345 since for ItemNo=5597 the location changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The LEAD function looks at the next row based on groups of ItemNo ordered by DateOfTest.

```
WITH abc AS (
SELECT
ItemNo
,DateOfTest
,NatureOfTumour
,Location
,Centre
,LEAD(NatureOfTumour) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo ORDER BY DateOfTest) as FutureNature
,LEAD(Location) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo ORDER BY DateOfTest) as FutureLocation
,LEAD(DateOfTest) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo ORDER BY DateOfTest) as FutureDateOfTest
FROM test_results
 )

SELECT
  ItemNo
  ,DateOfTest
  ,NatureOfTumour
  ,CASE
    WHEN FutureNature = 'IN'
      AND FutureLocation = Location
    THEN 'Yes' 
    ELSE 'NO' 
   END AS State_Change
  ,FutureDateOfTest - DateOfTest as Date_Diff
  ,Location
  ,Centre
from abc
WHERE NatureOfTumour = 'DC'
```

Comment: That's what he want I guess. I am following the post. Interesting.

Comment: But you should be aware of the IDs

Comment: Wouldn't partitioning on ItemNo remove the worry about IDs?

Comment: Yeah Yeah. Sorry I didn't saw it. Sorry Natec.

Comment: Hi Natec. Many thanks for the quick reply. I am very curious to try this out but unfortunately would have to wait till Monday, since I cant run code on my personal system. Would the output for this be a single row with ItemNo=2345?

Comment: Well no, it would return a single record for each case 'DC' with a yes/no flag if the state changed, and then the difference between current date and future date. You could adjust the query so it only returns records where DC changes state. Also - I would suggest changing your date column so it's 12-01-2006 instead of 12/2006. Also, you can use sqlfiddle.com to build your schema and test the output. Best of luck! :)

Comment: Thanks Natec. Seems this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help! If the answer works for you - can you mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You need a self join.  Something along these lines:

```
    SELECT
    d.ItemNo,
    i.DateOfTest - d.DateOfTest AS datediff,
    d.Location,
    d.Centre,
    d.Gen
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM demo
    WHERE NatureOfTumour = 'DC'
) d
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM demo
    WHERE NatureOfTumour = 'IN'
) i ON d.ItemNo = i.ItemNo
       AND d.Location = i.Location;
```

Comment: There is no `datediff` in Oracle

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorry - I started writing when it had MySQL flag.  I will delete

Comment: Thanks much Jonathan. The code looks much simpler in mysql. I wont be able to try running this out today since I can run code only from my work system; but just out of curiousity would the output for this be a single row for ItemNo=2345 which is the only ItemNo which satisfies all the conditions? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Jayden Yes that's right. If you run this, you just get the one record, 2345. I did test it on Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you could try this:
Let me know .
If you want in output only the rows who changed (GEN='Y'), change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN.

```
SELECT A.ITEMNO, A.DATEOFTEST, A.NATUREOFTUMOUR, A.LOCATION 
, CASE WHEN B.NATUREOFTUMOUR='IN' AND A.LOCATION = B.LOCATION THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS GEN_NEW
, CASE WHEN B.NATUREOFTUMOUR='IN' AND A.LOCATION = B.LOCATION THEN B.DATEOFTEST-A.DATEOFTEST  END AS TIME_PASS    
FROM TE A
LEFT JOIN TE B ON A.ITEMNO=B.ITEMNO AND B.NATUREOFTUMOUR<>'DC' AND A.DATEOFTEST < B.DATEOFTEST
WHERE A.NATUREOFTUMOUR='DC
```

OR (I can't understand from your question)

```
SELECT A.ITEMNO, A.DATEOFTEST, A.NATUREOFTUMOUR, A.LOCATION 
, CASE WHEN B.NATUREOFTUMOUR='IN'  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS GEN_NEW
, CASE WHEN B.NATUREOFTUMOUR='IN'  THEN B.DATEOFTEST-A.DATEOFTEST  END AS TIME_PASS
FROM TE A
LEFT JOIN TE B ON A.ITEMNO=B.ITEMNO AND B.NATUREOFTUMOUR<>'DC' AND A.DATEOFTEST < B.DATEOFTEST AND A.LOCATION = B.LOCATION
WHERE A.NATUREOFTUMOUR='DC'\\
```

Output

```
    ITEMNO  DATEOFTEST  NATUREOFTUMOUR  LOCATION    GEN_NEW TIME_PASS
1   2345    01.07.2006  DC              P           Y   153
2   2342    01.06.2006  DC              Q           N   NULL
3   5597    01.10.2001  DC              P           N   NULL
4   3878    01.05.2005  DC              Q           N   NULL
5   3878    01.06.2006  DC              P           N   NULL
```

Comment: No, I think his result would be only the rows of the unique id `2345` where the `natureOfTumor` changed from DC to IN and the location remained the same (in that case it remains `P`).

Comment: Hi Etsa. Many thanks for your reply. droidnation is right though. The Output should only be for 2345 since thats the only item number which satisfies all the constraints

Comment: It's really very easy to do that (as I explained in my answer, or using a Where condition).